# How do I remove text using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

For instance let say I have a text file:

```
worker1, 0001, company1
worker2, 0002, company2
worker3, 0003, company3
```

How would I use sed to take the first 2 characters of the first column so "wo" and remove the rest of the text and attach it to the second column so the output would look like this:

```
wo0001,company1
wo0002,company2
wo0003,company3
```

Comment: Have you researched this yourself? Pls post what you have tried, so we can help you make it work :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/^(..)[^,]*, ([^,]*,) /\1\2/' file
wo0001,company1
wo0002,company2
wo0003,company3
```

- `s/` begin substitution
- `^(..)` match the first two characters at the beginning of the line, captured in a group
- `[^,]*` match any amount of non-comma characters of the first column
- `,`  match a comma and a space character
- `([^,]*,)` match the second field and comma captured in a group (any amount of non-comma characters followed by a comma)
- match the next space character
- `/\1\2/` replace with the first and second capturing group

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response, it really help me understand it. Can I ask what does -E mean and what would I used to take the 3rd and 4th character of a word, for example "worker" I want to take "rk"

Comment: The `-E` enables extended regular expressions, without it you would have to escape 
each `(` and `)` for the capturing groups with a backslash ```\```.
To match the 3rd and 4th character you can match the first two characters, but omit them from the capturing group. The script would then begin with `'s/^..(..)`.

Comment: Matching the second field is unnecessary.

Comment: @Beta Matching the second field is needed to remove the space character, or not?

Comment: `sed 's/\(..\)[^,]*, /\1/' file`

Comment: @Beta Yes, that works if it's okay to leave the space before `company`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I hadn't noticed that. But I think I'd still prefer `sed 's/\(..\)[^,]*, /\1/;s/ //'` to holding two fields.